# Ebbinghaus model, differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> As you know, when a course ends, students start to forget the material they have learned. One model (Called the Ebbinghaus model) assumes that the rate at which a student forgets material is proportional to the difference between the material he or she currently remembers and some positive constant, $a$
>
> a) Write the differential equation.

My main problem is understanding the English, to write the differential equation.

I suspect that this is a logisic model.

Let $y = f\left(t\right)$ be the amount remembered from the course and $t$ be weeks,days, etc. since the course has stopped.

Now in the problem where it says proportional to the difference ...positive constant, $a$ that means that $k$ should be negative because of forgetting, thus $\dot y = -k(y-a)$ so $a$ will be what is learned for a lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, it is not important. Personally, I would interpret $a$ as "the quantity of knowledge a student can remember without problems of forgetting", which should be less than $y(0)$ to avoid problems of "spontaneous learning". You would then have to set $k>0$.

Comment: What if I put the condition that $y > a$? would that fix it?

Comment: Usually you don't put a condition like that on a differential equation. Notice that if $y=a$ then $\dot{y} = 0$, thus if $y>a$ for some point in time, then $y$ is always greater or equal to $a$, thus it is enough that you treat the case when $y$ is initially greater than $a$.